# finding how many times number2 is showing in number1

Tags: c

I am solving an exercise in C and I got stuck. I don't know the logic of the code to get to my solution. For example we enter 2 numbers from input let the numbers be `123451289` and `12` and I want to see how many times number 2 is showing at number 1 (if this is confusing let me know). For the numbers earlier the program outputs 2. I tried solving it here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2, counter = 0;
    scanf("%d%d", num1, num2);
    if (num1 < num2) {
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }
    int copy1 = num1;
    int copy2 = num2;
    while (copy2 > 0) {
        counter++; // GETTING THE LENGHT OF THE SECOND NUMBER
        copy2 /= 10;
//        lastdigits = copy1 % counter //HERE I WANT TO GET THE LAST DIGITS OF THE FIRST NUMBER
// But it does not work
    }
}
```

My question is how can I get the last digits of the first number according to the second one for example if the second number have 3 digits I want to get the last 3 digits of the first number. For the other part I think I can figure it out.

I must solve this problem WITHOUT USING ARRAYS.

Comment: So, for example, you want to know how many times 12 appears in 123451289, with the result being 2?

Comment: Your inputs are strings.  Do not bother converting them to integers.  Read them as strings, do string matching, output as strings.  Never convert.

Comment: If stored as strings, you can iterate over num1 and use strncmp to compare strlen(num2) letters.

Comment: Seems like you're asking 2 questions here. How many times 12 appears in 123451289 is completely different from getting the last 3 (for example) digits of a number (and what do you want to do with those digits?). Which is it? In either case, using strings instead of numbers will be easier as others have said if that's allowed.

Comment: Finding out how many times the digit sequence `1 2` appears in the integer 123451289 will be quite difficult. Figuring out how many times the substring `"12"` appears in the string `"123451289"` should be relatively easy.  I'm not even sure how I'd look for digit sequences in an integer — I'd probably convert the integer to a string, and then search for substrings.

Comment: @jarmod yes it counts the times a number was shown in the other number

Comment: I said "I'd probably convert the integer to a string", but you've now said you CAN'T USE ARRAYS.  (What *is* it with some instructors and their absolutely fetishistic phobia about letting students use arrays?)  In that case I'd use the same solution which Craig Estey has just independently devised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer that i was looking for but thank you all for helping :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
int num1,counter1,counter2,num2,temp,digit,copy1,copy2;
scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
if(num1<num2){
    temp = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = temp;
}
copy1 = num1;
copy2 = num2;
counter1 = counter2 = 0;
while (copy2>0) {
    counter1++;
    copy2/=10;
}
counter1 = pow(10,counter1);
if(num1> 1 && num2>1)
while (copy1>0) {
    digit = copy1%counter1;
    if(digit==num2){
        counter2++;
    }
    copy1/=10;
} else{
    if(num2<1){
        while (copy1>0) {
            digit = copy1%10;
            if(digit==copy2){
                counter2++;
            }
            copy1/=10;
        }
    }
}

printf("%d",counter2);
```

}

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work for `10 0`.

Comment: @chqrlie now it does ty :)

Comment: It does handle `10 0`, but not `0 0`

Answer (score 1):

The problem: find all the needles (e.g. 12) in a haystack (e.g. 123451289).

This can be done simply *without* arrays using a modulus of the needle. For 12, this is 100. That is, 12 is *two* digits wide. Using the modulus, we can
isolate the rightmost N digits of the haystack and compare them against the needle.

We "scan" haystack repeatedly by dividing by 10 until we reach zero.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int need, hay, counter = 0;

    scanf(" %d %d", &hay, &need);

    // ensure that the numbers are _not_ reversed
    if (hay < need) {
        int temp = need;
        need = hay;
        hay = temp;
    }

    // get modulus for needle (similar to number of digits)
    int mod = 1;
    for (int copy = need;  copy != 0;  copy /= 10)
        mod *= 10;

    // search haystack for occurences of needle
    // examine the rightmost "mod" digits of haystack and check for match
    // reduce haystack digit by digit
    for (int copy = hay;  copy != 0;  copy /= 10) {
        if ((copy % mod) == need)
            ++counter;
    }

    printf("%d appears in %d exactly %d times\n",need,hay,counter);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I'm afraid this does not work for 10 0. –
> chqrlie

A one line fix for to the modulus calculation for the 10/0 case. But, I've had to add a special case for the 0/0 input.

Also, I've added a fix for negative numbers and allowed multiple lines of input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int need, hay, counter;

    while (scanf(" %d %d", &hay, &need) == 2) {
        counter = 0;

        // we can scan for -12 in -1237812
        if (hay < 0)
            hay = -hay;
        if (need < 0)
            need = -need;

        // ensure that the numbers are _not_ reversed
        if (hay < need) {
            int temp = need;
            need = hay;
            hay = temp;
        }

        // get modulus for needle (similar to number of digits)
        int mod = need ? 1 : 10;
        for (int copy = need; copy != 0; copy /= 10)
            mod *= 10;

        // search haystack for occurences of needle
        // examine the rightmost "mod" digits of haystack and check for match
        // reduce haystack digit by digit
        for (int copy = hay; copy != 0; copy /= 10) {
            if ((copy % mod) == need)
                ++counter;
        }

        // special case for 0/0 [yecch]
        if ((hay == 0) && (need == 0))
            counter = 1;

        printf("%d appears in %d exactly %d times\n", need, hay, counter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
12 appears in 123451289 exactly 2 times
0 appears in 10 exactly 1 times
0 appears in 0 exactly 1 times
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> Good fixes, including tests for negative numbers... but I'm afraid large numbers still pose a problem, such as 2000000000 2000000000 and -2147483648 8 –
> chqrlie

Since OP has already posted an answer, this is bit like beating a dead horse, but I'll take one last attempt.

I've changed from calculating a modulus of needle into calculating the number of digits in needle. This is similar to the approach of some of the other answers.

Then, the comparison is now done digit by digit from the right.

I've also switched to `unsigned` and allow for the number to be `__int128` if desired/supported with a compile option.

I've added functions to decode and print numbers so it works even without `libc` support for 128 bit numbers.

I may be ignoring [yet] another edge case, but this is an academic problem (e.g. we can't use arrays) and my solution is to just use larger types for the numbers. If we could use arrays, we'd keep things as strings and this would be similar to using `strstr`.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef NUM
#define NUM     long long
#endif
typedef unsigned NUM num_t;

FILE *xfin;

int
numget(num_t *ret)
{
    int chr;
    num_t acc = 0;
    int found = 0;

    while (1) {
        chr = fgetc(xfin);
        if (chr == EOF)
            break;

        if ((chr == '\n') || (chr == ' ')) {
            if (found)
                break;
        }

        if ((chr >= '0') && (chr <= '9')) {
            found = 1;
            acc *= 10;
            chr -= '0';
            acc += chr;
        }
    }

    *ret = acc;

    return found;
}

#define STRMAX  16
#define STRLEN  100

const char *
numprt(num_t val)
{
    static char strbuf[STRMAX][STRLEN];
    static int stridx = 0;
    int dig;
    char *buf;

    buf = strbuf[stridx++];
    stridx %= STRMAX;

    char *rhs = buf;
    do {

        if (val == 0) {
            *rhs++ = '0';
            break;
        }

        for (;  val != 0;  val /= 10, ++rhs) {
            dig = val % 10;
            *rhs = dig + '0';
        }
    } while (0);
    *rhs = 0;

    if (rhs > buf)
        --rhs;
    for (char *lhs = buf;  lhs < rhs;  ++lhs, --rhs) {
        char tmp = *lhs;
        *lhs = *rhs;
        *rhs = tmp;
    }

    return buf;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    num_t need, hay, counter;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc > 0)
        xfin = fopen(*argv,"r");
    else
        xfin = stdin;

    while (1) {
        if (! numget(&hay))
            break;
        if (! numget(&need))
            break;

        counter = 0;

        // we can scan for -12 in -1237812
        if (hay < 0)
            hay = -hay;
        if (need < 0)
            need = -need;

        // ensure that the numbers are _not_ reversed
        if (hay < need) {
            num_t temp = need;
            need = hay;
            hay = temp;
        }

        // get number of digits in needle (zero has one digit)
        int ndig = 0;
        for (num_t copy = need; copy != 0; copy /= 10)
            ndig += 1;
        if (ndig == 0)
            ndig = 1;

        // search haystack for occurences of needle
        // starting from the right compare digit-by-digit
        // "shift" haystack right on each iteration
        num_t hay2 = hay;
        for (;  hay2 != 0;  hay2 /= 10) {
            num_t hcopy = hay2;

            // do the rightmost ndig digits match in both numbers?
            int idig = ndig;
            int match = 0;
            for (num_t need2 = need; idig != 0;
                --idig, need2 /= 10, hcopy /= 10) {
                // get single current digits from each number
                int hdig = hcopy % 10;
                int ndig = need2 % 10;

                // do they match
                match = (hdig == ndig);
                if (! match)
                    break;
            }

            counter += match;
        }

        // special case for 0/0 et. al. [yecch]
        if (hay == need)
            counter = 1;

        printf("%s appears in %s exactly %s times\n",
            numprt(need), numprt(hay), numprt(counter));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the program output:

```
12 appears in 123451289 exactly 2 times
123 appears in 123451289 exactly 1 times
1234 appears in 123451289 exactly 1 times
1 appears in 123451289 exactly 2 times
0 appears in 10 exactly 1 times
0 appears in 0 exactly 1 times
1000000000 appears in 1000000000 exactly 1 times
2000000000 appears in 2000000000 exactly 1 times
```

Comment: @SteveSummit Turnabout is fair play. I believe you've beaten me to the punch before [I just didn't tell you]

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work for `10 0`.

Comment: @chqrlie Right you are. I forgot to add a caveat on my original code about `need == 0`. But, I've generalized the code more added fixes for the `10 0` and `0 0` cases.

Comment: Good fixes, including tests for negative numbers... but I'm afraid large numbers still pose a problem, such as `2000000000 2000000000` and `-2147483648 8`

Answer (score 0):

This looks along the lines of what you're attempting.

You can use the pow() function from math.h to raise 10 to the power of how many digits you need for your modulus operation.

Compile with `-lm` or make your own function to calculate 10^num_digits

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int x = 123456789;
    double num_digits = 3.0;
    int last_digits = x % (int)pow(10.0, num_digits);
    printf("x = %d\nLast %d Digits of x = %d\n", x, (int)num_digits, last_digits);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
x = 123456789
Last 3 Digits of x = 789
```

Comment: I think the request is more general than that: how do I get the last N digits from number X where N is the number of digits in Y? That aside, I'm not sure this is really what the OP should be solving anyway.

Comment: @jarmod, I think it does but I edited to make it more clear

Comment: @jarmod you are absolutely right

Comment: @itmemilan That is what this code does. Your code already calculates the num_digits, it's your variable `counter`. The last N digits of X is equal to `(int)pow(10.0, counter)`. If you can't use the pow() function from the math.h library, then make your own function to calculate 10^counter

Comment: Yep ty that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to ask :- if number1 = 1234567 and number2 = 673, then, length of number2 or number2 has 3 digits, so, you now want the last 3 digits in number1, i.e, '456', if I'm not wrong.

If that is the case, then, what you did to find the number of digits in num2 is correct, i.e,

```
while (copy2>0) {
        counter++; // GETTING THE LENGHT OF THE SECOND NUMBER
        copy2/=10;
}
```

you can do the same for number1 and find out its number of digits, then you can compare whether the number of digits in number2 is less than that in number1. Ex, 3 is less than number of digits in number1, so you can proceed further. Let's say number of digits in number1 is 7 and you want the last 3 digits, so you can do iterate over the digits in number1 till count of digits in number2 and pop out each last digit and store them in an array.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    int num1,num2;
    
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    
    if(num1<num2){
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }
    
    int copy1 = num1;
    int copy2 = num2;
    
    while (copy1>0)
    {
        count1++;
        copy1/=10;
    }
    
    while (copy2>0)
    {
        count2++;
        copy2/=10;
    }
    
    // printf("num1 has %d digits and num2 has %d digits\n", count1, count2);
    
    if (count1 >= count2)
    {
        int arr[count2];
        int x = count2;
        int p = num1;
        int i = 0;
        
        while (x > 0)
        {
            arr[i++] = p%10;
            x --;
            p/=10;
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[j]);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

output : 8 7 6

let's say, num1 = 12345678, num2 = 158, then arr = {8,7,6}.

Comment: If you find it helpful and expected, mark it accept and upvote!

Comment: yes that would be easy if only my professor told us not to use arrays :), btw i forgot to mention that in my question sorry

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work for `10 0` and it uses arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You must determine the number of digits N of `num2` and test if `num1` ends with `num2` modulo 10<sup>N</sup>.

Note these tricky issues:

- you should not sort `num1` and `num2`: If `num2` is greater than `num1`, the count is obviously `0`.
- `num2` has at least 1 digit even if it is `0`.
- if `num1` and `num2` are both `0`, the count is `1`.
- if `num2` is greater then `INT_MAX / 10`, the computation for `mod` would overflow, but there can only be one match, if `num1 == num2`.
- it is unclear whether the count for `1111` `11` should be `2` or `3`. We will consider all matches, including overlapping ones.
- to handle larger numbers, we shall use `unsigned long long` instead of `int` type.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    unsigned long long num1, num2;

    if (scanf("%llu%llu", &num1, &num2) != 2) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (num1 == num2) {
        /* special case for "0 0" */
        counter = 1;
    } else
    if (num1 > num2 && num2 <= ULLONG_MAX / 10) {
        unsigned long long copy1 = num1;
        unsigned long long mod = 10;
        while (mod < num2) {
            mod *= 10;
        }
        while (copy1 > 0) {
            if (copy1 % mod == num2)
                counter++;
            copy1 /= 10;
        }
    }
    printf("count=%d\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that leading zeroes are not supported in either number: `101 01` should produce a count of `1` but after conversion by `scanf()`, the numbers are `101` and `1` leading to a count of `2`.  It is non trivial to handle leading zeroes as well as numbers larger than `ULLONG_MAX` without arrays.